# swipe activity to change another activity in android and show multiple Activity in a singleview?

Tags: android, git, page-flipping

Hi i need to swipe  on each activity page to change next view.How to animate a swipe effect in android.
how can i swipe the activity(Mi firstquestion)

My secoundquestion 
**show multiple Activity in a singleview?**

for example I have 4 activity Activity(1,2,3,4). In screen the 2nd activity should show in the center the next two activity (2 and 3 Activity)corner shows in the left and right in the page and if he again swiple it should be (2,3,4) from(123)Activity. How can i do this
the image i need is below

Comment: When you have two questions that are not even remotely related in their answer, do not create a single question post... post two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple Activities on one screen you should probably consider using `Fragment`s instead.  And for Swiping between Activities I would use a `ViewPager` and swipe between `Fragment`s.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/