# GestureDetector for many activities

Tags: android, gesture

I have an app that spans a dozen activities and I want all activities to respond the same to a few pre-set gestures. I'm wondering if I need to code the GestureDetector/GestureOverlay into each activity? This approach seems silly. I was thinking if it is possible to have a single gesture class that can be responsible for all the different activities. Am I thinking on a correct path?

BTW, I'm very new to Android.

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try the links it may help you

[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

[gesture detection](http://www.eridem.net/android-tip-010-left-and-right-swipe-gesture-events)

and the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645898/swipe-activity-to-change-another-activity-in-andoid-and-show-multiple-activity-i)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did look into those and got a rough idea of how gesture works. My other question was how could I write the code once and have it applied to my many activities in the same app. I'm not doing fragments but full screen activities and each of which needs to respond to the same gesture.

Comment: k let me think i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

1. Register to activity lifecycle callbacks
2. Once you get the callback for `onActivityCreated`, replace the `Window.Callback` with your own version of `WindowCallback` which implements `Window.Callback`.
3. Save the Actual activity `Window.Callback` and you can replace your custom `WindowCallback` with it on `onActivityPaused`

You don't have to write your logic in every activity